# cellForRowAtIndexPath Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have a NSMutable array with data.

I want in the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" fill the individual rows.

The table view keeps crashing and I do not know why.

The problem is in this line "cell.ergebnissLabel.text = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]".

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ErgebnisseCell";
ErgebnisseCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
NSDictionary*filtertNew = [self.nummeriertesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1]
cell.ergebnissLabel.text = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}
```

The error message looks like this.

```
2014-02-28 17:32:11.208 Info[2451:70b] -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10950c110
2014-02-28 17:32:11.210 Info[2451:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10950c110'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101caf295 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101a0d99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101d4045d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ca0b8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ca0738 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Info                                0x000000010001f0da -[ErgebnisseTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 394
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010069574a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 348
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010067bb1b -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2337
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010068cfc1 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100621943 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010021cdf2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100211959 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001002117da _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001001856e4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010018675c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001005c01f1 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 10863
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c3eb21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c3e3f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c5a26f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c59b83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103587df5 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001005c2003 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    22  Info                                0x0000000100036143 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001025a35fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks.

Comment: NSString does not "recognize" objectAtIndex.  Most likely because your variable `result` contains an NSString, not an NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

This two line gives you an error:

```
NSArray *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1]
[result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// This gives you array of string
[filtertNew allKeys]
// This gives you string (second in array)
[[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1]
//When you call that line you call 
[result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
//You call objectAtIndex: method on NSString object but there is not method like that on NSString
```

I believe you want to do:

```
cell.ergebnissLabel.text = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:row]
```

Comment: If I have understood them has to write into a string the result from the array. But unfortunately, I'm still doing something wrong.

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSDictionary*filtertNew = [self.nummeriertesArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *resultNew = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        cell.ergebnissLabel.text = resultNew;

Has anyone an idea.

Comment: @carlie - Greg explained to you that this line is WRONG: `NSArray *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1];`

Comment: @HotLicks this code takes second object from NSArray ([filtertNew allKeys]) which contains NSStrings so the result is NSString not NSArray.

Comment: @carlie as I said in my answer this line is wrong: NSArray *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1]; the result should be type of NSString not NSArray so it should be NSString *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1]; and the next line won't work (resultNew) because you cannot call objectAtIndex on NSString object. Please review my answer again.

Comment: And review my comment again.

Comment: @HotLicks sorry I misunderstand you.

Comment: Just so as to not further confuse @carlie, Greg and I (and jlehr) agree that `result` is incorrectly typed and is returning an NSString, not an NSArray.  There may be other bugs, but treating that NSString like it was an NSArray is the immediate cause of your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. First, your code obtains an instance of `NSDictionary` from an array:

```
NSDictionary *filtertNew = [self.nummeriertesArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

On the next line, you obtain an array of the dictionary's keys, which in all likelihood are instances of `NSString`. You then access the second key in the array and store it in a variable named `result`.

```
NSArray *result = [[filtertNew allKeys] objectAtIndex:1]
```

Unfortunately, although the `result` variable is typed `NSArray *`, the value you're assigning is a string, not an array. Next, you send `objectAtIndex:` to that string, which crashes the app because `NSString` doesn't have an `objectAtIndex:` method.

```
cell.ergebnissLabel.text = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

That's why you're seeing the following error message on the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10950c110'
```

This tells you that an instance of `NSString` was sent an `objectAtIndex:` message, and that since the instance didn't recognize the selector (i.e., the method name), it threw an exception.

However, you haven't included any information on what it is you're trying to do, so i would be difficult to tell you exactly what you'd need to do to get it working correctly.